# preg_replace ('/σ/', 'ς', $cat_name);

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

how can change only the last letter of any word of a string with regular expressions?

I use mb_strtolower() for change strings from upper to lower in Greek language and I have problem with final 's'.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) --  `\b` -- to match the start or end of a word.  Try

```
preg_replace ('/σ\b/', 'ς', $cat_name);
```

Comment: Either I'm doing something very wrong, or, with everything in UTF-8, the preg_replace gives me an empty string. Handling of UTF-8 string requires the 'u' modifier, but even there the support is only partial.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace (‘/σ\b/’, ‘ς’, $cat_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$s = "sdfΣ";
echo $s,"\n";
echo mb_ereg_replace("Σ\\b", 'ς', $s);
```

**EDIT**: Apparently, this doesn't work for greek leters, `preg_replace` will match "f", not the sigma.

Not that I know any greek, but `σ` is labelled as "Greek small letter sigma", so you ask for the lowercase version, it should still give `σ`.

`mb_strtolower()` should work. You're probably doing something wrong. Post the relevant portion of your program.

Anyway, with `preg_replace` and assuming both your script and `$cat_name` are encoded in UTF-8, it's:

```
echo preg_replace ("/\\w\\b/eu", 'mb_strtolower(\'\\0\', \'UTF-8\')', $cat_name);
```

for instance, if `$cat_name == "sdfÉ"`, this gives `sdfé`.

Comment: The problem is that uppercase sigma has two lowercase variants depending on the position within the word. So `mb_strtolower()` works halfway - it's not smart enough to handle the disambiguation.

Comment: @Tim OK, nice to know. So I guess the OP was just converting everything to `σ` and then wanted to replace the sigmas in the end of the words with `ς`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that I use is:
mb_internal_encoding("ISO-8859-7");
$cat_name=mb_strtolower($categories_name);
$cat_name=preg_replace('/σ\b/', 'ς', $cat_name);

The problem is that when I use
$cat_name=preg_replace('/σ/', 'ς', $cat_name);   work right and replace every  'σ' with 'ς'

My server has  PHP 5.2.6-1+lenny8 with Suhosin-Patch 0.9.6.2 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2010 09:07:33)

Local in my laptop I use Xamp for windows with PHP Version 5.3.1 and the switch \b work.
So the problem is in the different version of Php or in php.ini  ?

Thanks for the replies..